# Uniquely Identifying a device on user's log in

Tags: mongodb, firebase-cloud-messaging, nestjs

I am storing firebase cloud messaging tokens for every user when he logs in but I want to store every token against a deviceId which will be unique for every device (to remove fcmToken on logOut", I know I can get unique device Id in case of android but how can I get in case of web?

I searched out but mostly i am getting that its not that simple to get unique identifier because browsers dont provide us that, one option is uuid but that doesnt seem better approach either.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the device mac address and store it in the request using low level language or there is this package you could use to generate uuid [device-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-uuid).